# Unrecognized selector sent to instance when attempting to call an extension method via a swift bridging header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, unrecognized-selector, objective-c-swift-bridge

I'm trying to call Objective-C code from Swift. I [created a Swift Bridging Header](https://bohemianpolymorph.wordpress.com/2014/07/11/manually-adding-a-swift-bridging-header/), and added an import to the Objective-C file (e.g. `#import "UIColor+Utils.h"`).

The project builds, and I even get code completion, but when it attempts to execute that line of code, it crashes and says `unrecognized selector sent to class`.

What did I do wrong?

(Xcode 6.2, iOS 8.2)

Answer (score 13):

This is caused when you attempt to call an extension method from a file which is included in the bridging header, but isn't added to the proper target.

**To fix this, ensure that the file is a member of the same target as the one that is currently running**.

For example, if you are trying to call Objective-C code (e.g. `UIColor+Utils.m`) from your WatchKit Extension, then the .m file (e.g. `UIColor+Utils.m`) must have the WatchKit Extension in its **Target Membership** section.

For more information, see below.

---

If you include the .h file in the `Bridging-Header.h` file, but forget to add the file to the target, you will get the following behavior.

If you attempt to call a method on your own class (e.g. `ABCClass.doSomething()`):

- You will get code completion.
- You will get a build error: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64`.

If you attempt to call a class extension method (e.g. `UIColor.doSomething()`):

- You will get code completion.
- You will NOT get any build errors/warnings.
- When attempting to execute that line, you will get a crash: `unrecognized selector sent to class`.

Answer (score 0):

With xCode 8, when you add a file, make sure you choose the correct target from 'options'. I was choosing a folder and adding it directly to my project but somehow that was not setting the correct target.

[image]